# Adjusting a RHEL 8 install for a machine without a hard drive?

Tags: rhel, kernel, system-installation, initramfs, initrd

I've been working with a custom RHEL 8 image (basically the official ISO but with a kickstart for packages/configuration) on a CD and have gotten it to install without issue on a piece of hardware when it contains a hard drive. The hard drive is not necessary for the process as I install to an iSCSI target hosted on another machine on the network.

Having proven success to this point, the next logical step was to remove the hard drive since the machine had no use for it anymore. It still has 8GB of RAM which should be more than enough to handle vmlinuz and initrd.img but I cannot seem to get the install to proceed past that point.

I get EDD Read Errors at different sectors of the two files, then after awhile it proceeds to

`Unpacking initramfs...`

And then throws the error

`---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

where it hangs indefinitely. So while the EDD read errors seem to suggest a bad piece of media, I've gotten it to work when the hard drive is intact.

The next step I've taken is using the official RHEL 8 ISO on a CD and opted for the "Test and Install" step with some edits to the kernel line. It ultimately ends up looking like

`append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=RHEL-8-4-0-BaseOS-x86_64 rd.live.check rw inst.xdriver=vesa inst.text nomodeset nosoftlockup inst.nonibftiscsiboot`

Which gets me well past the issue and into the Anaconda part. Using the same line on my custom CD but adding

`inst.ks=cdrom:/kickstart.inst.ks.cfg`

does not get me any further than before. While I could very well be doing something wrong, the fact that I am using the same vmlinuz and initrd as the official ISO means that there must be some sort of configuration or setting that is hidden in the official media that I must explicitly declare.

I'm not as well-versed with the early files involved in the install process (before Anaconda) but maybe I need to create a special version of vmlinuz/initrd? Or do I need to somehow specify that the install needs to be loaded to RAM?

Comment: I've seen the same kernel panic message after installing a new version of the kernel. Red Hat indicates that the root cause of the problem is "Either the initrd declaration is missing from the new kernel's title statement in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, or the initrd/initramfs file itself is missing from the `/boot` directory." I'm guessing that the initrd/initramfs is trying to initialize `/boot` the hard drive and when it is not there, it fails.

Comment: [This article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_a_standard_rhel_installation/iscsi-disks-in-installation-program_installing-rhel) may be helpful.